# Understanding top command output

Tags: command-line, bash, top

Below is screenshot of top command output.

[image]

I want to understand memory and cpu information in this top's summary view.
I have following doubts:

1. Are the numbers for `us`, `sy`, `ni` etc in `%Cpu(s)` in third line are percentages of total hardware CPU processing power available? (I believe this is likely the case as I am unable to imaging anything else out of which % is shown.)

   [MAN page](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/man1/top.1.html) says:

   > Line 2 shows CPU state percentages based on the interval since the last refresh. As a default, percentages for these individual categories are displayed.

   SO, I believe this indeed mean "percentages of total hardware CPU processing power available", right?
2. What are the values in `%CPU` column? Is it percentages of total hardware CPU processing power available or percentage of current CPU utilisation, that is percentage of `%Cpu(s)` specified in third row? (I feel later, because total of value in `%CPU` column is greater than total of `us`, `sy` and `ni` values (which actually contributes to current CPU utilisation, if am not wrong.).

   MAN page says:

   > The  task's share of the elapsed CPU time since the last screen update, expressed as a percentage of total CPU time.

   Its not clear share out of "total hardware CPU processing power" or "current CPU utilization".

   MAN page says:

   > A task's currently used share of available physical memory.

   Again not clear whether its share out of "total RAM available" or "current memory utilization".
3. What are the values in `%MEM` column? Is it percentage of (hardware) RAM size or percentage of current RAM utilisation?

Answer (score 1):

You're confusing terms that are well defined. Let's break it down:

> ```
> As a default, percentages for these individual categories are displayed.  Where two labels 
> are shown below, those for more recent kernel versions are shown first.
>        us, user    : time running un-niced user processes
>        sy, system  : time running kernel processes
>        ni, nice    : time running niced user processes
>        id, idle    : time spent in the kernel idle handler
>        wa, IO-wait : time waiting for I/O completion
> ```

Yes this is of total CPU availabe - also see below.

> ```
> 1. %CPU  --  CPU Usage
>        The  task's share of the elapsed CPU time since the last screen update, expressed as a
>        percentage of total CPU time.
> ```

Let's see what [CPU time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CPU_time) means:

> CPU time (or process time) is the amount of time for which a central processing unit (CPU) was used for processing instructions ... Often, it is useful to measure CPU time as a percentage of the CPU's capacity, which is called the CPU usage. CPU time and CPU usage have two main uses.

I do agree that the wording is a bit odd, but I must assume that "total CPU time" is everything, including idle time. So I can only understand this as each task's CPU time as a percentage of the total elapsed CPU time - meaning the task's share of CPU resources out of total CPU available.

> ```
> 2. %MEM  --  Memory Usage (RES)
>        A task's currently used share of available physical memory.
> ```

There is only one way to understand this. "Share of available physical memory" is of course just that - so percentage of total available RAM.

Overall, it wouldn't make any sense to output neither CPU nor RAM as percentage of *current usage*, because this metric would change all the time. So percentage of *current usage* wouldn't have any practical value.

Comment: So, %CPU row (3rd row) is % out of **total** CPU processing power. %CPU column is sum of % of current utilization (**not total** ) of all cores? Hence, %CPU column is percentage of %CPU row value? I have exact two machines one which I ran same app and logged processing time, %CPU row and %CPU column of app. Here are observations: [link](https://i.postimg.cc/T2W1BBLk/image.png). In M1, %CPU row < %CPU col while in M2 its reverse. I am trying to make sense of this. Also, accordingly processing time also changes.

Comment: Sorry, I don't have the time. If you have issues with the `top` display, please address the developers. Thanks.

Comment: You can get CPU stats directly from `/proc/stat`, maybe use this to do your testing..